# Can we define feature relevance in terms of regression coefficients?

Tags: machine-learning

Can we define feature relevance in terms of regression coefficients? Lots of works report definition of feature relevance in terms of probability and mutual information but I did not find any literature defining the relevance of features in terms of regression coefficients although many works have experimentally proved this.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. What do *you* mean by feature relevance?  Presumably the definition should reflect that, but since you don't tell us what you mean by it, I'm not sure how we can answer.  2. You *can* define a word to mean anything you want, if you really want; it might not be a good idea, though, as it's liable to cause confusion if you use it in a way that differs from standard usage.  A rose by any other name still smells as sweet.  3. Can you list a few of the works that have experimentally proved "this"?  Also, what's "this"?  What have they experimentally proved?

Comment: This has been done many times over. Spending < 1min on the OLS wiki page will give you the information you need.